# How to re-fetch data from backbone collection within a requirejs module from a select box outside of module?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I've recently built a requirejs/backbonejs module that builds a table on my page.  The collection fetches the data and returns it in JSON, which i am parsing through and rendering.  It works fine up to this point, and the table renders beautifully on the page.

The API i am using to fetch the data requires that i pass in a time range.  So for the first draw of the table, i pass in a MS value to fetch the last 30 days of data.

I also have a filter section at the top of the page that allows me to choose how many days worth of data to fetch, either 1 week or 1 month.

how do i get this filter to reload the collection without redrawing the entire page?  or am i just implementing backbone/require incorrectly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with redrawing the entire page on `fetch()`. I do something kind of similar in which each time someone selects a display filter I fetch the data, reset the collection and re-render the view. I use a subview to display my data though, so actually I'm only re-rendering that and not the full page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think that's what i ultimately need to do.  I want to just redraw the table, not the entire page.  So if i'm understanding this right, in order to accomplish something similar to what you have done, i could build the dropdown filter as one view, and the table as a subview or 2nd view (or vice versa), and then set up an event on the filter to trigger a collection.fetch() on the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bang. Your last comment exactly.

You don't even need to setup an event trigger with this setup. When you fetch the collection, Backbone will automatically trigger a reset event for you.

Say you have your parentView which is the entire page. Somewhere in that parent view is your dropdown filter that triggers a `fetch()` event. You fetch the appropriate data (1 week or 1 month) and reset your collection.

Your child view (subview) has an event listener that's listening to your collection reset:

```
// Inside child view
// (the view that houses all the individual model views of the collection)

this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
```

And it simply re-renders itself when it hears that you reset your collection.

Note: once you get into the business of creating subviews and subviews of subviews, don't forget to properly clean up those subviews when you remove parent views (meaning make sure they're removed from the DOM AND detached from any event listeners they're bound to.) Otherwise you get nasty Zombie Views which eat up resources and cause strange messes. It's a popular recurring question here. ;-)

Comment: i've been messing with this concept with not much headway :(... when you re-render the view, shouldn't resetting the collection also clear out the html output? or is that something backbone expects you to do on your own? for some reason my code appends more rows after the fetch.

Comment: It depends on what your `render()` function does. For example, if your `render()` does something like `this.$el.append(something);` then yeah, you're going to have a bad time (keeps adding) My renders usually do `this.$el.html(this.template());` etc. It could be other issues too however. Why don't update your question with this comment + some code. I'd be happy to take a look at it in context.

Comment: I actually posted it earlier, as i am sure i'm missing something obvious.  i really appreciate your help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290447/double-rendering-view